# TransformFinalBlock with TripleDes(3DES) - DESMode.ECB in Dart/Flutter

Tags: c#, flutter, dart, encryption, 3des

I tried and looked for a solution to my problem, but I didn't find anything that worked.

I have a C# program that works perfectly. My task is to turn this program into Flutter, but I can't.

** The code (in C#) that works is this: **

```
private ICryptoTransform mDesEnc;
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider mDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
mDes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String("B4WOmhsRsOSD2ZRfhmULCcI0lR4kNiy6");
mDes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
mDes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
mDesEnc = mDes.CreateEncryptor();

mSeq = 2;
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mSeq.ToString());
var dec = mDesEnc.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
var ret = Convert.ToBase64String(dec);
//dec = 213, 5, 215, 181, 143, 185, 167, 134
//ret = "1QXXtY+5p4Y="
```

In Flutter, I tried to do this:

```
final key = base64.decode("B4WOmhsRsOSD2ZRfhmULCcI0lR4kNiy6");
print(key);
final seq = 2;
final bytes = utf8.encode(seq.toString());

mDes3CBC = DES3(
  key: key,
  mode: DESMode.ECB,
  paddingType: DESPaddingType.OneAndZeroes,
);

List<int> t = [];
t.add(bytes.last);

final encrypted = mDes3CBC!.encrypt(t);
print(encrypted);
```

but the result is: // [11, 195, 182, 192, 231, 57, 14, 15] (Needs to be like 'dec' in the other example).
different from expected.

Comment: The paddings differ: Zero Padding in the C# code, OneAndZeroes (ISO/IEC 7816-4) in the Dart code.

Comment: In this library I didn't find the padding option zero. Do you have any suggestions for this? @Topaco

Answer (score 0):

I created the padding in a auxiliar function and didn't add the padding from the library.

```
void teste() {
    final key = base64.decode("B4WOmhsRsOSD2ZRfhmULCcI0lR4kNiy6");
    print(key);
    final seq = 2;
    var bytes = new List<int>.from(utf8.encode(seq.toString()));
    _paddingZero(bytes);

    mDes3CBC = DES3(
        key: key,
        mode: DESMode.ECB,
        paddingType: DESPaddingType.None,
    );

    final encrypted = mDes3CBC!.encrypt(bytes);
    print(encrypted);
}

_paddingZero(List<int> data) {
    int l = 8 - data.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        data.add(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: By disabling built-in padding and using custom padding you are on the right track. However, your implementation only works for plaintexts that have a length of 1 block (8 bytes).

Comment: This is more than enough for me, i only need to encrypt one int which will be incremented every iteration. Thx for your contribuition.